# How to iterate on the same cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to use some scripts in my google sheet between two sheets.

The first sheet is a listing of all games played by people (Name = Foo) and the second one is just a statistic one who incremente by one everytime the game is played (Name = Bar). So here's my formula :

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2);"";IF('Foo'!A:A = A2;B2+1;B2))
```

The column A in my Bar sheet is just a recap of all the game played. Because i iterate over the same cells as where my formula is written, i had to change the properties of my google sheet to let this happen (Files > Properties > Calcul)

My problem is : The B2+1 doesn't work at all :( What did i miss ?

Link of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mjg9UEH5HNEzj3l25p6cw8wvEs1B2uko9AFwimy-gas/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide a sanitized sample of your spreadsheet so that I can be sure I understand what you want to do? Also, have you considered using Apps Script?

Comment: @OMila Here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mjg9UEH5HNEzj3l25p6cw8wvEs1B2uko9AFwimy-gas/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you just want to count how many times a Game appears in Foo, you can use this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2);"";COUNTIF('Foo'!A:A;A2))
```

Check [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) for further information on `COUNTIF`.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: This is exactly what i want ! Thanks you @OMila !